# create dataframe from nested dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary as given below:-

```
d = {'Tom'  :{'A' : '25', 'B' : '34'}, 
     'Jim'  : {'A' : '34', 'B' : '19'}, 
     'john' : {'A' :'56' , 'B' : '32'}}
```

How can I construct the dataframe like this from the above dictionary?

| Names | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | 25 | 34 |
| Jim | 34 | 19 |
| John | 56 | 32 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `pandas.DataFrame.from_dict` specifying the orientation of index, eg:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
```

(Then optionally reset your index and give it a name..., eg:)

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').rename_axis('Names').reset_index()
```

Comment: It gives the dataframe with another index as 0,1,2. Is there a way we can remove that and just get the columns Name, A and B ?

Comment: Umm... don't reset the index then... it makes more sense to have your name as an index anyway... (if you want it named.... then remove the `.reset_index()` from the 2nd example)

Answer (score 0):

Just create a `DataFrame` with `d` and `transpose` it:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(d).transpose()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
       A   B
Tom   25  34
Jim   34  19
john  56  32
```